# Why can´t I convert a String to JSON object in Android?

Tags: php, android, json

I´m receaving an array from php to android and I receive the following format in an String:

```
["Rick","Anne","Carl"]
```

but when I execute:

```
 JSONObject myjson = new JSONObject(the_json);
```

I get:

```
 org.json.JSONException: Value ["Rick","Anne","Carl"] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

why? I send the array fom php with

```
 echo json_encode($arreglo);
```

I suppose this sentence send the stream with the correct format, no?

Answer (score 0):

> why?

Because the JSON does not represent a JSON object. It represents a JSON array. To parse a JSON array using the `org.json` classes, use `JSONArray`, not `JSONObject`.

Comment: so, what have Ito do is: `JSONArray myjson = new JSONArray(the_json);`?

Comment: @ReneLimon: Yes. Or, switch to a better JSON parsing library (Jackson, Gson, etc.0.